# How do I import a Reminder.app lists into a Notes.app checklist?

Tags: macos, notes.app, reminders

I want to transform my list of reminders in Reminders.app into a checklist inside a note in Notes.app. I tried dragging the list from the list of lists from Reminders to Notes and that didn't work. I tried dragging the contents of the Reminders list to a new Notes note and that imported the content with a `[ ]` before each item. Is there a way to convert theses into Notes' native checklist items?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer.

Comment: @user3439894 Yeah, that solution would definitely work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following **AppleScript** *script* will take the selected *Reminders* in **Reminders** and make a new *Note* in *Checklist format* in **Notes**. This can be run in **Script Editor** or saved as an **AppleScript** *application*.

- Note: As this *script* uses **UI Scripting**, when run from **Script Editor**, it must be added to **System Preferences** > **Security** & **Privacy** > **Accessibility** in order to *run*. As an **AppleScript** *application*, the application would need to be added.

```
tell application "Reminders" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}
delay 0.1
set theNotesChecklist to ""
set theReminders to get the clipboard as string
repeat with thisParagraph in paragraphs of text of theReminders
    try
        set theNotesChecklist to theNotesChecklist & text 5 thru -1 of thisParagraph & return
        delay 0.1
    end try
end repeat
tell application "Notes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "n" using {command down}
    keystroke "l" using {shift down, command down}
    delay 0.5
    keystroke theNotesChecklist
    delay 0.1
    key code 51 -- # Delete - Deletes the last 'return' typed.
end tell
```

The above *script* assumes the selected *Reminders* in **Reminders** have no information associated with them. In other words, other then the `Name` *property* no other associated *properties* have been set. If other *properties* have been set, add the `if` *statement* to the `repeat` *loop* as shown in the *code* below:

```
repeat with thisParagraph in paragraphs of text of theReminders
    try
        if thisParagraph starts with "[ ]" then
            set theNotesChecklist to theNotesChecklist & text 5 thru -1 of thisParagraph & return
            delay 0.1
        end if
    end try
end repeat
```

Note: With **UI Scripting**, the value of the `delay` *commands* may need to be changed on your system and or additional `delay` *commands* added as appropriate.

Comment: Awesome, it works! I just had to add a few more delays to get it work for me. See the edit.

Comment: @Steve Moser, Yeah, that's understandable and why I always add that note. On my system, as originally written, it worked as was posted. That's one of the pitfalls of UI Scripting